# Unable to connect to SQL 2016 RC3

Tags: sql-server

I am testing connectivity to a new installation of SQL 2016 RC3 instance on an Azure network.  I'm create a .udl file and attempt to connect using the SQL Server name but it fails with the following message.

The text of the .udl file is:

```
[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=domain\username;Data Source=TheSQLServer
```

The error message is:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Data Link Error
---------------------------
Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]Specified SQL server not found.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

If I change to the IP of the SQL Server it works!  What could be causing this?

Comment: After installing SQL Management Studio i see a new error.  I think this is the problem http://www.power-programming.co.uk/post/2008/12/19/SQL-Network-Interfaces-The-target-principal-name-is-incorrect-Cannot-generate-SSPI-context.aspx

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot generate SSPI context" is an error due to handshake between client, SQL and domain controller. Mostly its solved by creating right SPNs.
Based on your description, it looks like an issue with name resolution. Did try pinging?

Troubleshooting guide - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811889

Comment: yes i can ping via machine name and IP. It is only the .udl file giving me hell.